# Move Checkout Shipping Options in Woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying the move the shipping options in my woocommerce checkout out of review-order.php and into form-checkout.php

I have taken the code

```
<?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?>
    <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And moved it to my themes form-checkout.php the problem is that it will now not update the shipping when I enter or change the address. This has been accepted as a solution online but I think woocommerce has updated since then.

I think the problem is that the shipping options are now not updating when update_checkout Ajax is called but I am unsure how to change this.

Thank You

---

EDIT: I think I have an idea of how to do this. I have created a template checkout/shipping-options.php with

```
    <?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
?>
<div class="card card-shipping mb-3 woocommerce-checkout-shipping-table">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        Select Shipping
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body ">
                        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?>
                        <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>
                        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Then in my functions.php I have added

```
    function woocommerce_checkout_shipping_options( $deprecated = false ) {
        wc_get_template(
            'checkout/shipping-options.php',
            array(
                'checkout' => WC()->checkout(),
            )
        );
    }
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping_option', 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping_options', 10 );
```

Then added

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping_option' ); ?>
```

into form-checkout.php

and updated the woocommerce/includes/class-wc-ajax.php update_order_review function to include

```
// Get order review fragment.
ob_start();
woocommerce_order_review();
$woocommerce_order_review = ob_get_clean();

// Get checkout payment fragment.
ob_start();
woocommerce_checkout_payment();
$woocommerce_checkout_payment = ob_get_clean();

// Get checkout shipping fragment.
ob_start();
woocommerce_checkout_shipping_options();
$woocommerce_checkout_shipping_options = ob_get_clean();

// Get messages if reload checkout is not true.
$reload_checkout = isset( WC()->session->reload_checkout );
if ( ! $reload_checkout ) {
    $messages = wc_print_notices( true );
} else {
    $messages = '';
}

unset( WC()->session->refresh_totals, WC()->session->reload_checkout );

wp_send_json(
    array(
        'result'    => empty( $messages ) ? 'success' : 'failure',
        'messages'  => $messages,
        'reload'    => $reload_checkout,
        'fragments' => apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_update_order_review_fragments',
            array(
                '.woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table' => $woocommerce_order_review,
                '.woocommerce-checkout-payment' => $woocommerce_checkout_payment,
                '.woocommerce-checkout-shipping-table' => $woocommerce_checkout_shipping_options,
            )
        ),
    )
);
```

All I need to work out now is how to update the update_order_review ajax without editing the core files.

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem and found a solution.

Step 1: Copy and remove the following code in review-order.php

```
<?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?>
    <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Step 2: Insert it wherever you want in form-checkout.php and add a div around it

```
<?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?>
    <div class="my-custom-shipping-table">
        <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Step 3: Open functions.php of your child theme and add following code

```
function my_custom_shipping_table_update( $fragments ) {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="my-custom-shipping-table">
        <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    $woocommerce_shipping_methods = ob_get_clean();
    $fragments['.my-custom-shipping-table'] = $woocommerce_shipping_methods;
    return $fragments;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_update_order_review_fragments', 'my_custom_shipping_table_update');
```

And that's a wrap.

Found the solution here: https://www.ibenic.com/customize-woocommerce-checkout-pages/

Comment: Hey, I also use the same solution but unfortunately the ajax reload is only appearing to payment methods and order review table, but not for shipping methods. Maybe you find workaround for that?