Change location of WooCommerce chekout shipping options allowing ajax update
I've recently moved part of the checkout form (wc_cart_totals_shipping_html()) from review-order.php to form-billing.php in my WooCommerce setup. Previously, I was using jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout'); in form-shipping.php to dynamically update shipping methods, but it's not working in form-billing.php anymore.
Can someone guide me on how to trigger the update of shipping methods (wc_cart_totals_shipping_html()) dynamically in form-billing.php using jQuery or AJAX? I want the shipping section to update based on changes in billing details (e.g., country selection).
<?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?>
        <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

I recently moved part of the WooCommerce checkout form related to shipping (wc_cart_totals_shipping_html()) from form-shipping.php to form-billing.php within my theme's WooCommerce templates. Previously, I was using jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout'); successfully in form-shipping.php to dynamically update shipping methods based on user actions
review-order.php
<?php
/**
 * Review order table
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://woo.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 5.2.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
?>

<table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="product-total"><?php esc_html_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php
        do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents' );

        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

            if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                ?>
                <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
                    <td class="product-name">
                        <?php echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) . '&nbsp;'; ?>
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times;&nbsp;%s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . '</strong>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                        <?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="product-total">
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }

        do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents' );
        ?>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>

        <tr class="cart-subtotal">
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <td><?php wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Shipping', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <?php
            // Get the chosen shipping method ID from the cart session
            $chosen_shipping_method_id = WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods')[0];

            // Get the shipping methods available for the current package
            $shipping_packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();

            // Initialize variables
            $chosen_shipping_method_label = '';
            $chosen_shipping_method_cost = '';

            foreach ($shipping_packages as $package_key => $package) {
                // Check if the chosen method is available in this package
                if (isset($package['rates'][$chosen_shipping_method_id])) {
                    $chosen_shipping_method = $package['rates'][$chosen_shipping_method_id];
                    $chosen_shipping_method_label = $chosen_shipping_method->label;
                    $chosen_shipping_method_cost = wc_price($chosen_shipping_method->cost);
                    break; // Exit loop once the chosen method is found
                }
            }
            ?>
            <td><?php if (!empty($chosen_shipping_method_label)) : ?>
                    <?php echo esc_html($chosen_shipping_method_label) . ':'; ?> <?php echo $chosen_shipping_method_cost; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
            <tr class="cart-discount coupon-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                <th><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon ); ?></th>
                <td><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>



        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
            <tr class="fee">
                <th><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></th>
                <td><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ( wc_tax_enabled() && ! WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) : ?>
            <?php if ( 'itemized' === get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_total_display' ) ) : ?>
                <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_tax_totals() as $code => $tax ) : // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited ?>
                    <tr class="tax-rate tax-rate-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                        <th><?php echo esc_html( $tax->label ); ?></th>
                        <td><?php echo wp_kses_post( $tax->formatted_amount ); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <tr class="tax-total">
                    <th><?php echo esc_html( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ); ?></th>
                    <td><?php wc_cart_totals_taxes_total_html(); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total' ); ?>

        <tr class="order-total">
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <td><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total' ); ?>

    </tfoot>
</table>

form-billing.php
<?php
/**
 * Checkout billing information form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-billing.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.6.0
 * @global WC_Checkout $checkout
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
?>
<div class="woocommerce-billing-fields">
    <?php if ( wc_ship_to_billing_address_only() && WC()->cart->needs_shipping() ) : ?>

        <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing &amp; Shipping', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>

    <?php else : ?>

        <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', $checkout ); ?>

    <div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
        <?php
        $fields = $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' );

        foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
            woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) );
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', $checkout ); ?>

    <?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>
        <div class="shipping-container">
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?>
            <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && $checkout->is_registration_enabled() ) : ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-account-fields">
        <?php if ( ! $checkout->is_registration_required() ) : ?>

            <p class="form-row form-row-wide create-account">
                <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox">
                    <input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" id="createaccount" <?php checked( ( true === $checkout->get_value( 'createaccount' ) || ( true === apply_filters( 'woocommerce_create_account_default_checked', false ) ) ), true ); ?> type="checkbox" name="createaccount" value="1" /> <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Create an account?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
                </label>
            </p>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_registration_form', $checkout ); ?>

        <?php if ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'account' ) ) : ?>

            <div class="create-account">
                <?php foreach ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'account' ) as $key => $field ) : ?>
                    <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_registration_form', $checkout ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Trigger update_checkout event when a relevant change occurs (e.g., billing country change)
        $('#billing_country').change(function() {
            $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
        });

        // Log a message when the checkout is updated via AJAX
        $(document.body).on('updated_checkout', function() {
            console.log('Checkout updated via AJAX');
        });
    });
</script>


yeah, im sorry i moved it from review-order.php to form-billing.php

Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66663964/move-shipping-options-outside-woocommerce-checkout-order-review/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66474563/move-checkout-shipping-options-in-woocommerce/

function my_custom_shipping_table_update( $fragments ) {
    global $pickup_button;
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="my-custom-shipping-table">
        <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>
    <?php
    $woocommerce_shipping_methods = ob_get_clean();
    $fragments['.my-custom-shipping-table'] = $woocommerce_shipping_methods;
    return $fragments;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_update_order_review_fragments', 'my_custom_shipping_table_update');

